# How do I properly include a custom field in the new_order API payload for an enumerator custom field type?

Tags: rest

The Sticky.IO API V1 documentation is not clear as to what the structure of the custom_fields JSON node should be.  I have had success submitting custom fields for the plain text custom field type, but have failed to figure out the enumeration field type.

Here is a working sample of a text type payload for the custom_fields node:

```
"custom_fields": [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "value": "Custom Field Value Here"
    }
]
```

I thought that the enumeration payload should look like this, but I get a response stating 'Invalid option id supplied' even though the option_id supplied has been verified to be the correct option_id:

```
"custom_fields": [
    {
        "id": 13",
        "option_id": 28,
        "value": "Option Text Value"
    }
]
```

Does anyone have any experience with custom fields for the Sticky.IO new_order API?

I have tried passing the option_id as an array, but that didn't work either.  It would help if I could find precise documentation for the custom_fields object.

By the way, the documentation on the Sticky.IO API documentation page is incorrect. It states that the node name for custom fields is "custom_field" but I know for a fact it is "custom_fields" as the text data type I can get to work without issue using the payload above.

NOTE: I would have been more specific with the tags on this post, but I don't have enough rep to create new tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this figured out on my own, but for anyone stumbling across this post looking for the answer to the same question, here it is:

The custom field object's value property is dynamic meaning that it accepts the appropriate data type for the specified custom field's set data type in Sticky.IO.  Here is the actual structure of the custom_fields node:

```
"custom_fields": [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "value": {Custom Field Value}
    }
]
```

Note that the value property is an object rather than a set data type.  Pass the appropriate data type represented by the definition of the custom field.  For the enumerator data type, what is expected is an array of integers - the integers being the option_id(s).

Data Type IDs:

```
1 = Text: pass the value property as a string
2 = Decimal: pass the value property as a number
3 = Date: pass the value property as a date string in universal time 
          with the format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
4 = Boolean: pass the value property as a number - 1 meaning true, 0 meaning false
5 = Enumerator: pass the value property as an array of option_id (integer)
```

For the enumerator data type `5`, Check the custom field's `is_multi` boolean property to determine if multiple option_ids can be passed.  If true, multiple option_ids can be passed.  If false, only one option_id can be passed, but still must be passed as an array.

So to answer the question, here's how the payload should look for the example in the question:

```
"custom_fields": [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "value": [28]
    }
]
```